# Java - Periodic updates from MySQL

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, event-dispatch-thread

I am developing a Scoreboard Java application for my work. It uses MySQL to store the score values and a Java application accesses them and displays them on a projector. So far I have managed to create a Java application using Swing. I display all of the scores using jLabels so that they can be updated without completely redrawing the scoreboard.

Now, I need to get the scoreboard to update periodically. I have attempted to use `Thread.sleep` but I don't know how to interrupt the thread. The reason I need to interrupt the thread is that if the number of entries to display on the scoreboard is changed on the config panel, the scoreboard must redraw in order to display the right nummber.

Currently `sleep` works fine in the code so long as I don't touch anything. But as soon as I change anything in the `ConfigPanel` things go awry.

---

```
package au.thewebeditor.scoreboard.apps;

import java.lang.*;

public class Program {
    private static Scoreboard sb;
    private static ConfigPanel cp;

    public Program(){
        sb = new Scoreboard();
        cp = new ConfigPanel();
    }

    public static void redrawScoreboard() throws NullPointerException{

        try{
            sb.dispose();
        } catch (NullPointerException e){
            //DO NOTHING
        }
        sb = new Scoreboard();
        try {
            cp.toFront();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            cp = new ConfigPanel();
        }
        constUpdates();
    }

    public static void showConfig(){
        cp.setVisible(true);
        cp.toFront();
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments){
        new Program();
        constUpdates();
    }

    private static void constUpdates() {
        boolean go = true;
        while (go){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                Scoreboard.updateScores();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //DO nothing
            }
        }
    }

}
```

---

When the connfiguration has been changed `redrawScoreboard()` is called.

At the moment, when `redrawScoreboard` is called it just sits in the queue while `constUpdates` keeps counting to 5000. How do I interrupt the `sleep` so I can redraw the scoreboard. Is `sleep` even the best option here? Or should I try something else?

Comment: Check out `javax.swing.Timer` you can `stop` this whenever you like.  I'd also check out [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) as you have some potential EDT violations going on there as well...

Answer (score 1):

1. you have an issue with [Concurency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), any create, update, modify Swing GUI must be done on `Event Dispatch Thread`, maybe reason for  wrapping `sb.dispose()`; into `try - catch` by throws `NullPointerException`
2. Swing GUI must be created on [Initial Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)
3. there no reason to recreate a new [Top-Level Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) every 5th. seconds, reuse `JComponents` added to contianer on app's start_up
4. use [util.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) to invoke [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html),

Comment: Thank you for all of the links. I am researching SwingWorker and Concurency now. FTR, `updateScores` doesn't create a new Top-Level Container (to my knowledge of TLCs) it just performs `setText` on all of those nifty `JLabels`.

Answer (score 1):

Calling constUpdates takes the current thread an puts it in an infinite loop.
If the config UI is calling it it will put the UI thread in an infinite loop.
It'd be better just to have that loop in the main function.

Should you get an InteruptedException you should break out of the loop, not keep going.

You've a heady mix of static and non-static things, try to make it so that objects get passed arround instead.

If you want the config to ask the scoreboard to redraw, pass it the scoreboard so it can call redraw directly and leave the polling alone.